# PDE by separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve by separation of variables $u_{t} = u_{xx}$, $-\pi \leq x \leq \pi$ subject to the conditions $u(x,0)=0$, $u(\pi,t)-u(-\pi,t)=2\pi$, $u_{x}(\pi,t)-u_{x}(-\pi,t)=0$.

My understanding of solving this question is much worse than I previously thought and I am really struggling with it. I would really appreciate any help; I will respond to answers and comments but I may have to be walked through this quite slowly until it clicks. Thank you in advance!

Edit: I've tried starting with $u=T(t)X(x)$ which separates to $T′+\lambda T=0$ and $X′′+\lambda X=0$, and then trying different values of $\lambda$ for the latter equation, but the results I've got don't seem right (in that I seem to get different answers each time I try)

Comment: @JKnecht I've tried starting with $u=T(t)X(x)$ which separates to $T' +\lambda T = 0$ and $X'' +\lambda X = 0$, and then trying different values of $\lambda$ for the latter equation, but the results I've got don't seem right (in that I seem to get different answers each time I try).

Answer (score 0):

The function $v(x,t)=x$ is a solution of the heat equation, and
$$
                  v(\pi,t)-v(-\pi,t)=2\pi,\\
                  v_{x}(\pi,t)-v_{x}(-\pi,t)=0,\\
                  v(x,0) = x.
$$
Therefore, $w(x,t)=u(x,t)-v(x,t)$ will satisfy the heat equation with
$$
          w(\pi,t)-w(-\pi,t)=0,\\
          w_{x}(\pi,t)-w_{x}(-\pi,0),\\
          w(x,0)=-x.
$$
These are the conditions of a more standard problem with periodic conditions, the separated solutions of which are $w_n(x,t)=T_n(t)X_n(x)$, where
$$
    X_n(x)=A_ne^{inx}+B_ne^{-inx}, \;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots\\
    X_0(x)=A_0 \\
    T_n(t)=e^{-n^2t}.
$$
The solution $w(x,t)$ can also be written as
$$
                w(x,t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}C_n e^{inx}e^{-n^2t}.
$$
The only condition that needs to be matched is $w(x,0)=-x$, which determines $C_n$:
$$
         -x = w(x,0) = \sum_{n-\infty}^{\infty}C_ne^{inx},\;\;\; -\pi < x < \pi \\
     \implies C_n = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}xe^{-inx}dx.
$$
Finally,
$$
         u(x,t) = x-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}xe^{-inx}dx\right]e^{inx}e^{-n^2t}
$$